# Did anyone ever remark on or explain Nog's small stature?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

As seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aron_Eisenberg#Early_Life):

> Eisenberg was born with only one partially functioning kidney and received a kidney transplant at the age of 17. This stunted his growth at 5' (1.52 m)

And he was 24 at the time *DS9* started,  when Nog was 16 (born 2353).

Obviously,  it's no coincidence that such a diminutive actor was cast to play a Ferengi teenager.   Nog's height then goes on to seem especially small compared to other Ferengi adults as the series progresses.  The contrast with Jake Sisko is stark who shot up like a beanstalk, as well as all the other Starfleet officers in general.

Now, we know Nog persisted like this far into the future.   For example, we have Capt. Nog, around fifty years in the future in "The Visitor":

[image]

So,  here's the question:

## In-universe, did anyone ever explain or remark on Nog's unusually small height (after he was fully grown)?

Comment: Only commenting because it's a minor thing not really addressing the guts of your question, but I always liked this relevant scene where Martok references Nog being shorter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JqFG_7wRKM&t=85s

Comment: Nog acknowledges that he's short in [*DS9: Satisfaction is not guaranteed*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Star_Trek_Deep_Space_Nine_Worlds_of_Deep/m0iOo_Pa3nQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=short+ferengi+nog&pg=PA88&printsec=frontcover); - *Nog was short even by Ferengi standards and he wondered as he made his slow-but-sure way down the tunnel how the previous owner ever thought this would make a good getaway method*

Answer (score 36):

I found no mention of any comments about Nog's size *in relation to other Ferengi*. So I have no canon quote to explain his height.

For explanation as to why there is no mention of it, I looked into his height relative to other Ferengi. In absolute terms, 5' would make Nog the second-shortest known Ferengi, taller only than [Kol](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kol). Ferengi average ~5' 4 1/4" with a standard deviation of 2.2716, so Nog's height puts him in the bottom 3% of known Ferengi --- very, very short, but not unreasonably so.

To reach these conclusions, I've gone through every Ferengi actor and checked their height, then done some basic analysis (double-counting actors who appear as multiple Ferengi, not counting Nog, and using inches as the unit of measurement).

If the height was unavailable from IMDB, then I omitted the actor/actress.
I found actor/actress information from links on [this list](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Ferengi)

- Armin Shimerman - Quark - 5'6"
- Lou Wagner - Daimon solok, Krax - 5'2"
- Lee Arenberg - Gral, Prak, Bok - 5'4"
- Tracy Walter - Kayron, Berik - 5'6"
- Jeffrey Combs - Brunt, Krem - 5'7"
- Ethan Phillips - Farek, Ulis - 5'6"
- Josh Pais - Gaila - 5'7"
- Jason Marsden - Grimp - 5'3"
- Leslie Jordan - Kol - 4'11"
- Hamilton Camp - Leck - 5'2"
- Michael Snyder - Qol, Morta - 5'5"
- Clint Howard - Muk - 5'7"
- Henry Gibson - Nilva - 5'3"
- Helene Udy - Pel (female) - 5'1"
- (I do not count Jeri Ryan, since her body was not the Ferengi)
- Wallace Shawn - Zek - 5'2"

Comment: Did you include Nog himself in your calculation of the mean and variance? If so, I count 1 who is 4'11'' = 4.91666..., 1 who is 5', 1 who is 5'1'' = 5.08333..., 4 who are 5'2'' = 5.1666..., 2 who are 5'3'' = 5.25, 3 who are 5'4'' = 5.333..., 2 who are 5'5'' = 5.41666..., 5 who are 5'6'' = 5.5, and 4 who are 5'7'' = 5.58333... So, the mean should be (4.91667 + 5 + 5.08333 + 4*5.16667 + 2*5.25 + 3*5.33333 + 2*5.41667 + 5*5.5 + 4*5.58333)/23 = 5.34058, shorter than the 5.36111 you got. And for the standard deviation I get 0.19929, so Nog is about 1.7 standard deviations from the mean.

Comment: ...and using the normal curve calculator [here](http://davidmlane.com/hyperstat/z_table.html), it seems that for a normal curve with mean of 5.34058 and standard deviation of 0.19929, 4.37% would be expected to be at a height of 5.0 or lower.

Comment: Even if you didn't include Nog, I think there's a mistake in the number you give for the standard deviation...I plugged the sequence 4.91667,5.08333,5.16667,5.16667,5.16667,5.16667,5.25,5.25,5.33333,5.33333,5.33333,5.41667,5.41667,5.5,5.5,5.5,5.5,5.5,5.58333,5.58333,5.58333,5.58333 into the mean and standard deviation calculator [here](https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/standard-deviation.php) and got 5.356 for the mean (very close to your value of 5.361), but 0.1893 for the standard deviation (very different from the value you gave of 2.3094).

Comment: I calculated Standard deviation and other data using inches, not feet, and I did not include Nog in the calculations. I've edited to add those explanations.

Comment: I also double-checked my numbers - and updated them. If you still get a different answer, I'll triple-check.

Comment: Thanks, your answer about expressing the standard deviation in inches cleared up my confusion, and your new slightly altered standard deviation of 2.2716 inches matches what I got.

Comment: I find it awesome that Ethan Philips (Neelix) and Jeffrey Combs (Weyoun/Shran) played Ferengi.  I didn't recognize either watching the show.  (Cept for the time Neelix was made up to be a Ferengi, but I'm guessing that doesn't count).    I plan to look for those episodes now.

Comment: @userLTK Memory alpha should tell you what episodes each Ferengi was featured in (unless it's somebody like Nog who showed up in tons)

Comment: @Jeutnarg I found them on IBDM and show are on Netfix, so easy to look up.   I've seen Menage a Troi several times (not a favorite, but just cause it happened to be on).  Never recognized Ethan Phillips and I never knew that Jeffrey Combs played Brunt.   Not a major character but on a number of episodes.   In my defense, the Ferengi makeup does make them harder to recognize, though I recognized Quark as the principal in Buffy in about 2 seconds but his might be a more distinctive face.  Going to do some re-watching for sure, cause I feel I should have recognized those actors and I didn't.

Answer (score 26):

## No explanation is offered, but it doesn't seem to be that unusual for Ferengi.

There's no direct in-universe explanation of Nog's short stature, but short statures do not seem to be uncommon amongst fully-grown Ferengi.

For instance, Quark is **5'5" / 1.66 m** (going by actor Armin Shimerman's height), making Quark shorter than most of *DS9* 's main characters.  After Nog and Quark, Kira is the next shortest at **5'8" / 1.72 m** (going by Nana Visitor's height).  Most of *DS9* 's main characters are **at or above 5'11" / 1.8 m tall**.

[image]

It could be something that runs in Quark's family, but Ferengi do, on the whole, seem to be shorter than humans, Vulcans, and other frequently featured humanoids in Star Trek.

[image]

Granted the Ferengi in the above image are sitting down, **but this guy on the left** does seem quite small in stature.  There is also a very large height differential here:

[image]

The five-inch difference between Quark and Nog could lie within the normal range of height variation for Ferengis, without necessitating a medical reason.

Finally, there is a brief indirect remark about Nog's height — by Nog himself, in relation to Jake.  From ["Shattered Mirror"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/492.htm):

> **NOG:** You and I friends? I don't think so.
>
> **JAKE:** Why not?
>
> **NOG:** You're **too tall**. I don't trust tall men. Tall women, that's a different story. Here. See for yourself.

The dialogue suggests that Nog finds his own height normal and Jake's abnormal.

Comment: I don't question that Ferengi are short, but this is really short.  Corollary:  do we know he was cast for the presumed height of a Ferengi teenager as I've assumed?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Short for humans sure, but for Ferengi?  My hypothesis is that even if he is on the short side for a Ferengi, he probably is not so short so as to suspect a medical condition (in-universe).

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I've seen interviews with Eisenberg where he describes his height as a selling point for the role, so presumably it was part of what sealed the deal. The fact that his height wasn't a plot point shows that it was seen to be consistent with the normal range of Ferengi heights.

Comment: Maybe he is but that seems like a post-justification.   Even so,  it doesn't mean no one would even remark on it.  Did you intend to be addressing that with the "no"?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : My "no" directly responds to "In-universe, did anyone ever explain or remark on Nog's unusually short stature (after he was fully grown)?"

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Are you looking for an explanation or will any remark do?  There is a brief remark.  I'll add it in.

Comment: Lacking an explanation, a remark is the next best.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Check it out.

Comment: Hmm.... not sure.   Jake is abnormally tall.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : But that's my point exactly.  The fixation is on Jake's excess height rather than Nog's lack of height.  We're making an assumption that Nog is short in-universe, but I don't think we can make that assumption; the fact that it is not remarked upon is consistent with his being in the normal range for Ferengi.

Comment: It could be surmised that shortness is an attractive feature among Ferengi, since many of them are in the habit of crouching over at all times. A trend that appears to gradually decline toward the end of DS9.

Comment: @Praxis, maybe this image is helpful? http://i278.photobucket.com/albums/kk98/Karmorgor/rikerferengistaredown.jpg

Comment: @ThePopMachine : That's great.  I'll work it in, thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that all Ferengi are short?!? That's specist talk, hoo-mon!!!

Answer (score 13):

There was a throwaway line in *[One Little Ship](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/One_Little_Ship_(episode))*, in which three Defiant crewmembers are sent through a spatial anomaly that substantially (and temporarily) reduces their size.

Kira finds the mission hilarious, while Worf does not "see what is so funny about being small" … cut to Nog, who somewhat defeatedly agrees, "neither do I".

This appeared, at least to me, to be a humourous reference, lampshading Nog's height.

I'm not aware that it has been referenced, even in this indirect fashion, at any other time.